# AutocompleteTextView setText or setHint not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, autocompletetextview, settext

So in my first activity i'm getting the current location as currentLocation through reverse geocoding and i use  **sharedPreference** to pass the value to the next activity (**second.java/class**). This class consist of an autocompleteTextView whose values are stored in an array.

Now what i want is when the user goes from the first activity to the second activity the autocompleteTextView should contain the location obtained from the first class as a **hint** or a **Text**

So this is my **firstclass.java**

```
Toast.makeText(this,currentPlace, 1000).show(); //works
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefss",  getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("CurrentPlace", currentPlace);
editor.commit();
```

and my **secondclass.java**

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefss",  getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
String curlocation;
from = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et_login_form);
curlocation = editor.putString("CurrentPlace","");
from.setText(curlocation); //doesn't work
from.setHint(curlocation); //doesn't work
```

and this is my **XML**

```
        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/et_login_form"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

and i've tried setting the text in xml throught

```
android:Text= "sample text"
android:Hint= "sample text"
```

which shows up in the graphical view but not in the MobilePhone

Comment: is there not text visible, when you do setText()

Comment: You need to use editor.getString("CurrentPlace","");

Comment: have you setted the right contentView for the second class??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
curlocation = preferences.getString("CurrentPlace","");
```

instead of

```
curlocation = editor.putString("CurrentPlace","");
```

**editor** only used for store value in **sharedPreference**. but for getting you only user **instance of sharedPreference**.

Comment: sorry, i get the value appended say if the first time i start the app i get aaaa and when i go back and click next i get aaaaaaaa. the value gets appended. any ideas how i can flush the preference once its got ?

Comment: Sandy, the link given by you does not exist.Please give us correct link.

Comment: check this link http://sandyandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2013/05/demo-shared-preference.html

Answer (score 0):

try this one because you again put in shareprefrence now try to get value fron sharedpreference.

```
curlocation = editor.getString("CurrentPlace","");
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
curlocation = editor.putString("CurrentPlace","");
```

with

```
curlocation = editor.getString("CurrentPlace",null);
```

Comment: if i use **editor.getString("CurrentPlace","");** im getting The method getString(String, String) is undefined for the type SharedPreferences.Editor

Answer (score 0):

in XML file it should be.

```
android:text= "sample text"
android:hint= "sample text"
```

Comment: I think you have used `setText` and `sethint` it should be `text` and `hint`

Comment: sorry my bad got a little confused, but yea ive used text and hint only